# How to write a merge statement into function snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am actually new to snowflake.

I am trying to create a task in which it calls a function.

but I am not able to create a function with merge statement in it.

I tried to do the below

```
create or replace function fx_01()
returns null
as 
$$
Merge into tb1 
using tb2
on
1.a = 2.a

when matched
then delete
$$;
```

I am not able to create a function.

I just need a skeleton of the code.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Need to able to create a function which has a merge statement in it

Comment: If you just want a skeleton merge statement then why not just take one of the examples in the Snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge ?

Comment: Tasks call stored procedures, not functions. Since you cannot create a SQL UDF that has a merge in any case, you can change this to a stored procedure.